# TCP/UDP Hole Punching and Hybrid P2P + Client/Server Architecture

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, p2p, hole-punching

I have a hybrid architecture where A is a client trying to request content from B, which is a server that is potentially behind a NAT (though not necessarily). S is a server acting as the go between for A and B to use hole punching in the following manner:

A contacts S and says I want to get something from B. S gives A B's last known IP address and port, and A starts trying to contact B. At the same time, S gives B A's IP address and port, and B starts trying to contact A.

S will **NOT** act as a relay server; after connecting with each other, all communication will take place in a direct connection between A and B. If they are unable to connect directly the connection will fail. I have this problem with both UDP and TCP.

My question is, what is the most efficient way for keeping S up to date with B's IP address and port, so that any number of As can connect to B at any time. I'd also like the solution to be able to handle a situation where if the NAT that B is behind messes around with the ports (such as incrementing them by 1), I would be able to "guesstimate" as to what the port actually is.

The solution I have thought of (but I'm not completely satisfied with):

Update S with B's IP address and port by sending a request from B to S every X seconds.     My issue with this is that if X is too high, S will not have the proper information for B, and if it is too low it would impose overhead on both B and S. I suspect this will end up being the final answer, and that the trick is going to be to find the proper value for X.

Comment: As I understand, As are requesting the content directly from B by making a connection and in order to establish the connection, they request the IP and port address of B from the server (S). I think, As can connect to the server and when they request a content from B, it first uploads its data to server so that As can download the content from the server.

Comment: No, I'm not able to use relaying in this situation. I'll update the question

Comment: OK. In this situation, B sends its IP information to server only if it is changed. So, when an information query is received from A, server sends a UDP segment with the related port of B in order to acknowledge that the current information of B is up-to-date. If it fails, it means that B is down (or the info is wrong) and no information should be returned to A. Otherwise, IP and port of B is sent to A.

Comment: A contacts S and says I want to get something from B. S gives A B's last known IP address and port, and A starts trying to contact B. At the same time, S gives B A's IP address and port, and B starts trying to contact A. The issue is, without constantly making requests to S from B, how do I ensure that the hole in B will stay open